# Is the etymology of the word "pandaemonium" in any way related to that of the mythological figure Pandora? 

Tags: etymology

Do *pandemonium* and Pandora (she of the box) come from the same etymological source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to answer your question, you can compare user7834's answer with this [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Pandora)

> 1570s, first mortal woman, made by
>   Hephaestus and given as a bride to
>   Epimetheus, from Gk. pandora
>   "all-gifted," from pan "all" + doron
>   "gift," from PIE base *do- "to give."

so the two words aren't probably related except for the fact that both words use the Greek word πᾶν (pan, "all")

Comment: +1 Exactly. Note that the Greek word *daimôn* comes from Proto-Indo-European root **da-*, "divide", which is, as far as we know, not related to PIE root **do-*, "give".

Comment: @Cerberus thanks for that! :) I'm learning a lot! :)

Answer (score 5):

> Coined by John Milton in "Paradise Lost," Pandæmonium, from Ancient Greek πᾶν (pan, “all”) (equivalent to English pan-) + Late Latin daemonium (“evil spirit, demon”), from Ancient Greek δαίμων (daimōn, “demon”).

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pandemonium